# Is there a Google API to calculate how related two terms (e.g. search terms) are?

Tags: json, statistics

Is there any way to estimate the relevance between two terms as objectively as possible using any of the APIs provided by Google? This would exclude personal suggestion or "clouds" Google uses.

Ideally I would like to get the output in json so I can plug it into C# easily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Number of results for both searches at once / min(number of results for search A, number of results for search B)` ?

Comment: Yes I know the math, I am looking for actual ways to retrieve that data from google.

Comment: This isn't a C# question; removing tag.  (It is barely a JSON question IMO).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post a big "probably not."  That is among the most proprietary information that Google needs to make money and it is almost certainly not publicly available.  (Questions of the form "is there a" are hard to answer definitively; but I think this reasoning adds value so posted as answer.)

Comment: Thanks, what if I would have used duckduckgo or another search engine that displays the same results for everyone regardless of history, should I be ok with making the estimates by the amount of pages found per the combination of the two terms?

Comment: @user2138167 I have noooooooooo idea what you are trying to do therefore nooooooo idea what you should be okay with.

Comment: Well that was kinda rude, I am working on artificial intelligence and I am trying to get the app to determine the most appropriate word out of dozens of words programmatically.